# Android Gradle Javadoc broken after upgrade to Gradle 7

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc

A few days ago I upgraded to the new Android Studio Arctic Fox release, which also now requires Gradle 7

Prior to the upgrade, I had the following javadoc task, which worked perfectly

```
def javaDocsAllowList = [
    "com/mycompany/SomeFile.java",
    "com/mycompany/OtherFile.java",
    ...
]

task javadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.compile
    include javaDocsAllowList
    destinationDir = file("./docs/javadoc")
}
```

Now though, it's all broken.

First error was

`Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer`

so I change the classpath line to:

```
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.implementation
```

Then I get

`Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.`

so I add

```
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
```

THEN I get a bunch of errors that it cannot find symbol for @Nullable and other attributes.

Other stackoverflow answers suggest adding this, which I do:

```
afterEvaluate {
  javadocs.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
    variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath.files
  })
}
```

This fixes the errors resolving @NonNull, etc, but now I am left with a bunch of errors where JavaDoc cannot resolve my own code, such as:

`void addNotificationsListener(@NonNull NotificationsListener listener);` (cannot find symbol NotificationsListener)

These seem to be reduced when I add more files to the AllowList, but I explicitly do not want to generate documentation for these other files. Help!

Why did Gradle 7 break all the JavaDocs and how can I fix it?

(recap: this is my failing task:)

```
task javadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)

    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.implementation
    include javaDocsAllowList
    destinationDir = file("./docs/javadoc")

    afterEvaluate {
        javadocs.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
            variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath.files
        })
    }
}
```

---

Update: based on suggested gist https://gist.github.com/Robyer/a6578e60127418b380ca133a1291f017?, I changed my task to the following:

```
task javadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.name == 'release') {
            owner.classpath += variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath
        }
    }
    include javaDocsAllowList
    destinationDir = file("./docs/javadoc")
}
```

However this makes no difference; it still gets the same error where it cannot resolve my own code

`void addNotificationsListener(@NonNull NotificationsListener listener);` (cannot find symbol NotificationsListener)`

Comment: Already tried something like this: https://gist.github.com/Robyer/a6578e60127418b380ca133a1291f017?

Comment: @MatPag tried that, but sadly it doesn't help

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? :)

Comment: @Pod nope. We threw out JavaDoc and switched to using Doxygen instead. Turns out, it produces much nicer docs anyway

Comment: was this module an aar that depends on an aar? Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906540/

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using gradle version 7.0.2 and Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2, and to generate sourcesJar, javadocs and javadocJar, I use:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    archiveClassifier.set('sources')
    archivesBaseName ="singleAdapter-1.1.0"
}
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.name == 'release') {
            owner.classpath += variant.javaCompileProvider.get().classpath
        }
    }
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    archiveClassifier.set('javadoc')
    archivesBaseName = "singleAdapter-1.1.0"
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

Finally, the resulting files can be found at:

1. project view -> myModule/build/docs/javadoc - for javadoc
2. project view -> myModule/build/docs/libs - for sourcesJar and
   javadocJar

I've posted it on my Github Gist: [Here](https://gist.github.com/vanskarner/3eae3e4545e3f8d39435c0096e2a09a4)

I hope that in your case I can help you.

Comment: How do I accomplish this in my case, the above code doesn't work with my Gradle. Not able to generate at least a single documentation for a single class. Pls see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78119162/unable-to-generate-android-javadoc-documentation-in-latest-android-studio-giraff

Comment: Have you tried pasting the code into the build.gradle of the app, for example I used the same code to generate the documentation for a library in my repository: https://github.com/vanskarner/SingleAdapter/blob/master/singleAdapter /build.gradle, each task runs a different resource.