# Android Studio fails to generate Javadocs due to packages not existing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

When I try to generate Javadocs for my projects using the Android Studio tool I get a series of errors that say a bunch of packages I am using do not exist.

```
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:8: error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Intent;
                      ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:9: error: package android.graphics does not exist
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
                       ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:10: error: package android.graphics does not exist
import android.graphics.Point;
                       ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:11: error: package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Bundle;
                 ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:12: error: package android.util does not exist
import android.util.Log;
                   ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:13: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.Display;
                   ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:14: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.View;
                   ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:15: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.WindowManager;
                   ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:16: error: package android.widget does not exist
import android.widget.ImageView;
                     ^
C:\Users\Jadon\AndroidStudioProjects\QRHunterApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\qrhunter\loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity.java:26: error: cannot access ViewGroup
public class loginQRCodeGeneratorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ^
  class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found
javadoc: error - fatal error encountered: java.lang.NullPointerException
javadoc: error - Please file a bug against the javadoc tool via the Java bug reporting page
(http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com)
for duplicates. Include error messages and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$MembersPhase.runPhase(TypeEnter.java:934)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.doCompleteEnvs(TypeEnter.java:282)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$MembersPhase.doCompleteEnvs(TypeEnter.java:877)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:251)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:266)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:266)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:266)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.complete(TypeEnter.java:198)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:583)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:560)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.JavadocEnter.main(JavadocEnter.java:79)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.JavadocTool.getEnvironment(JavadocTool.java:206)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:576)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:432)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:345)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.execute(Main.java:63)
    at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.main(Main.java:52)
12 errors

"javadoc" finished with exit code 4
```

I have read every answer on this website I can find for a solution to this, and all I have found is to use the -bootclasspath argument in the extra arguments for the generate javadocs tool.

I tried to use that but it is deprecated, so I switched to the -sourcepath argument with the path to my android.jar, it doesn't seem to change anything
-sourcepath C:\Users\Jadon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\android.jar

If anyone knows some way to fix this I would be forever in your debt. This is killing me as I need to have the javadocs generated for my grade.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem and finally found a solution. Put this in your build.gradle (Module) and execute it by pressing Strg+Strg and type `gradle generateReleaseJavadoc`

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."

        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        destinationDir = file("$rootDir/javadoc/")
        failOnError false

        doFirst {
            ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
            classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)

            options.addStringOption "-show-members", "package"
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and as a workaround, I generated the JavaDocs using Intellij. It's free for students, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for this problem:

1. Implementing android.jar in the module that needs it:
   Go to Project View `>` External Libraries `>` unfold Android API X Plataform `>` click right in android.jar `>` Copy Path `>` Absolute Path `>` go to gradle and paste the path in implementation files:

```
dependencies{
implementation files('Paste Here')
}
```

Then try again go to Tools > Generate Javadoc and generate it.

Don't forget to remove the (implementation files...) line once you've managed to generate your javadoc.

2. Use gradle as indicated by this solution that I published recently: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096187/9902249)

Answer (score 0):

I found that unchecking "Include JDK and library sources in -sourcepath" in the Android Studio "JavaDocs" applet window allowed a build of javadocs for classes in the com.example.xxxx java folder.